# Creating foreign key objects in Castle Active Record

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

I have a project which I've used Castle Active Record as the DAL technology.

My object relationships are like this...

A `Route` contains many `Waypoints`.

What I want to do is add a waypoint to a route without retrieving the route from the database but I can't quite work out how to do it.

I already know the route ID so thats not a problem. Will initialising a route with the correct ID and assigning it to the waypoints Route property before I save achieve this result?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: And did you get an error when you tried the approach you mentioned above?

Comment: Only just spotted this comment. I'll check later and update.

Comment: This actually doesn't throw an error, I should have just tried it instead of suspecting it wouldn't work and looking for docs about another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since someone favourited this question I'm gonna answer it myself since I now know the answer. If anyone has a problem with that then they can do any flagging or whatever needs to happen.

Initialising a Route with the correct ID and assigning it to the waypoints Route property before you save is enough to link the waypoint to the existing route.

I guess I didn't find any documentation for it because it's just such a simple solution.